# Golub and Van Loan 3rd Ed Basic Algos Getting Started

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-mathematics

I am trying to get my brain back into matrix algebra, and I am starting right from the beginning of the standard **Matrix Computations**, by Golub and Van Loan ( 3rd Edition ).  A couple of the practice problems in chapter 1.1 have to do with writing algorithms for matrices raised to a power.  I don't see these cases explicitly described in the text, and I'm having trouble connecting the dots here.  Specifically, problem **P1.1.3**:

**P1.1.3** Give an algorithm for computing $C = (xy^T)^k$ where $x$ and $y$ are $n$-vectors.

So I understand the $xy^T$ is an outer product, so $C$ is going to be an $n$-by-$n$ matrix.  I can easily use one of the matrix multiplication update algorithms for the case where $k=2$. For example, for the a algorithm

$$C=AB + C$$

where $A,B = xy^T$, then $A(i,j),B(i,j)=x^{}_{i}y^{}_{j}$. So the matrix update algorithm would be:

```
for i = 1:n:
    for j = 1:n:
        for p = 1:n:
            C(i,j) = x[i]*y[p]*x[p]*y[j]
```

I used the variable $p$ here since $k$ has a different meaning in the question. There are a few other variations of the matrix multiplication algorithm that could be substituted.  But the big thing I'm not getting is how to expand this algorithm to account for $k>2$ in $(xy^T)^k$?  It seems like there needs to be another loop in the algorithm to account for the $k$. But also I have this gut feeling that I'm supposed to be using outer product updated algorithm, which takes the form $A=A+xy^T$.

Big thing I'm missing is seeing how these *update* algorithms correspond to raising matrices to powers, or multiplying many times.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE**

After considering the suggestion in the comments, I think I have it figured out.  So as in the comment, $$C=(xy^T)^k$$ can be re-written as $$C=(y^Tx)^{k-1}(xy^T)$$ where $y^Tx$ is a dot product, so this represents a scalar.  $y^Tx$ is an outer product matrix, so this operation simplifies to a scalar-matrix multiplication.  From the text we could use a simple matrix-scalar algorithm to accomplish this.

Let $${\alpha} = (y^Tx)^{k-1}$$
$$A = xy^T$$
Then
$$C={\alpha}A {\implies} c^{}_{ij}={\alpha}a^{}_{ij}$$

Comment: Don't know what the authors suppose to be done, but $(xy^{T})^k = x(y^{T}x)^{k-1}y^{T}$ (and now the thing getting powered is a scalar).

Comment: ... and you should see this "update" (as a multiplication of the whole matrix by a single number) from the algorithm you're posting... when you fix it ;)

Comment: @metamorphy you're right.  this exact this what actually going through my head this morning.  It then becomes a dot product and an outer product.  A matrix times a scalar, which I think is referred to as a gaspy algorithm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the purpose of the question is to let us take advantage of associativity of matrix product.

A naive way of compute this would be to compute $xy^T$ explicitly. This involves complexity $O(n^2)$ and then multiply $xy^T$ to the power $k$ directly, $O(n^3)$ each time, we are doing this $k$ times, hence the overall complexity would be $O(kn^3)$.

A smarter way has been pointed out in the comment, that is first we compute $y^Tx$, first, complexity $O(n)$, then raise to the power $k-1$, and then multiply it to the product of $xy^T$. Overall complexity would be $O(\max(n^2,k))$.

Remark about your attempt:

It is not clear to me what do you mean by $A,B = xy^T$ and in your for loop, only the last $p$ matters because you are overwriting it. I can't tell what is going on though.

Comment: My notation probably isn't correct, I just meant, in the case when $k=2$, A and B both are set to $xy^T$, so then i was showing how to do $C=AB$ in this case.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. so you need the loop to add. Metarmorphy's method is faster.